# How to enable Twitter's new UI?

Tags: twitter

New Twitter UI was launched recently. Some can use it already, others can't. By the way, I realized an interesting fact. When I visit twitter.com from favstar.fm, I can always see the new UI. But on the other hand, when I visit there by typing "twitter.com" into Chrome's omnibox, all I can see is just the previous UI.

I think some information in HTTP header does this trick because URL is the same between when typing by myself and when jumping from favstar.fm but Referer.

But I'm so unfamiliar with web technology that I can't survey by myself.

Would somebody tell me why this happen, or how they detect and provide different UI to each case? Is the server to be connected different? And it's differed by the Referer?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting, I don't see the new UI when I try to link to Twitter from Favstar.fm. What I do see is a bug on the other hand. If you log in to [Favstar.fm](http://Favstar.fm) with an account that has the new UI and then log out of Twitter in a different tab and then login with an account that does'nt have the new UI, when you tab over to Favstar.fm and then link to Twitter from there, the current logged in user (who doesn't have the new UI) will appear to have the new UI when you click on the direct link from Favstar. If you then proceed to navigate Twitter though, the UI reverts to the [#newtwitter](http://www.quora.com/Will-Twitter-release-its-new-search-API-called-phoenix-Can-we-ever-use-it) Phoenix site which is the old new Twitter.

I had a look at un-encrypted HTTPS from Fiddler2 and here is what I discovered.

The Phoenix Twitter is using a different version of the CSS obviously which can be found below, (I believe the URL is personalized so you won't be able to access it unless your logged in under my name).

> https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1492998967phoenix/css/phoenix_core.bundle.css

The new UI is calling a series of CSS files from a different directory.

> ```
> https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1492998967/t1/css/t1_core.bundle.css
> ```
>
> (I changed the number for privacy reasons)

Hope this sheds some light into whats going on. **I don't think you can forcibly make the UI for your account always render the new UI unless you were to use a greasemonkey script or browser plugin that redirected the usage of the CSS files.**

Comment: really, it was not for everyone, I didn't know! Thank you for the survey, that's interesting, and it may be an advance to understand this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

Websites like Twitter tend to "roll out" major changes to their users rather slowly. The reasons being as follows:

- If there are any bugs/issues, they'll catch them before everyone has it and the problem should be less difficult to deal with.
- All the scripts/stylesheets/images and general "site assets" are cached on your computer and if everyone requested the new version all at once, the site would probably crash.

In any case, this means that many different people will get it at different times and they may do it a particular country at a time, or in the same order that people joined Twitter or any number of different ways.

Twitter have stated that if you update to the latest version of Twitter on Android or iOS, you will get the new UI faster. I found that you need to update it, ensure you've signed in and have a good play with it and then you should have it within a couple of hours.

You are right, however, that there may be some irregularities when requests are coming from other websites. This may be for compatibility, for security whilst it's still new or any number of other reasons. This should probably become normal and more consistent soon.

Hope that answered your question/provided useful information. :)

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I am interested in technically reasons to determine whether providing new UI or old one. I updated my iOS's twitter app surely, but the UI stays old. And interestingly, when I asked this question I was able to see new UI via favstar.fm but no longer I can now. Anyway, thanks for a nice comment :)

Comment: It may take some time to update, and you must use the app to some extent. You might have to spend some certain time on the app, or tweet from it or something similar. It's also possible that you're running a browser/system configuration which the new UI does not yet support.

Comment: ummm... i think i've used it for a long while relatively and, of course, tweeted many times. could you give me some examples "a browser/system configuration which the new UI does not yet support"? i have no idea with it... (cf. i'm using Chrome, and the OS is Mac OS X Lion) btw, i don't know it relates with this problem or not, that when i open twitter on the web, through the browser, it says it can't load tweets somehow. but, if i turned "always use https" on, it works as expected, strangely.

Comment: Ah. Well. That is precisely the same configuration I use to access Twitter, so I wouldn't expect any issues there. The issues with irregularities when using HTTPS could be down to something wrong with your cache. Would be worth trying clearing it. Also, you don't happen to be browsing through a proxy?

Comment: no, I don't. but,hey, it seems that I finally got new UI! I did nothing, it comes really suddenly. though the reason why I couldn't have got it til now is still remained, but anyway, thank you so much so far! it's been seemingly settled :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after logging in to the new twitterclientsoftware on my iPhone. As @spolsky noted "Not confusing at all!"

Comment: oh really, but for me it didn't happen even after loggin in to the iPhone's new Twitter app..... mysterious

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** as of today, the new UI is default for all users. See [@Support's tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/Support/status/169936852256690176).

> As of today, all users have been upgraded to the new version of Twitter. Looking for a feature? Take the tour here: https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169519

Download and install the latest version of the native app for iPhone or Android. See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/MobileSupport/statuses/144919695554920451).

> If you've downloaded the latest iPhone/Android app (and opened it on your device) you're all set. Web access will come soon! #newlook

Also, scroll to the bottom of [this](http://fly.twitter.com/) page.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, certainly we can get it on iPhone but not on web browser for everyone. As for on web browser, it's still uncertain.

Comment: Several articles state that if you install the latest version of the native app (and login), then you will have the latest version of the web app in the browser as well. See [this one](http://www.dailytut.com/social-networking/how-to-enable-new-twitter-design.html), for example.

Comment: Interesting, but it might not have worked on my case. what's the criterion...

Comment: yes, I'm not sure about the validity of this as well. And several others state on the various [articles](http://www.dailytut.com/social-networking/how-to-enable-new-twitter-design.html#comment-383009412) that this is not working for them either. My account mysteriously started to render the new UI on several occasions navigating through the site and I have not installed any versions of Twitter clients on any of my devices. I think this actually may be related to using multiple logins or copies of your login. I am experimenting with this factor a lot.